# Convert part of path to standalone path

Tags: inkscape

I have several paths that appear to be connected even though there is no connection between them:

[image: image description]

I would like to split the letter `e` apart from the path. I found an [answer suggesting the use of Break apart option](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9237528/607407). But that causes the letter inner parts to be all black:

[image: image description]

So how do I remove existing path fragment, that is not connected to the rest, so that it doesn't break and looks just like before? How do I turn selected part of line to standalone line?

Comment: The inner path of the letter e is responsible for the hole. If you remove it the hole will disappear and the area will be black. Why would you want to remove it without changing the look?

Comment: Mind explaining the downvote?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- mark your text "ep"
- select node toolbar (1)
- transform to path (2)
- ungroup (3)

done. Now you can manipulate the e-Shape individually. 
That's all.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Starting from a text object 'ep':

- select the text
- do Path -> Object to path. You now have a group of objects (letters)
- Ungroup (Shift+Ctrl+G or Object -> Ungroup)
- select a letter (eg. the 'e')
- do Path -> Break Apart
- the 'e' will now consist of two objects: the outer shape, and the inner part (the 'hole'). The inner part will be black. Select it, and set the fill color to white or transparent (with left-click on the palette, or by using Shift+Ctrl+F Fill and Stroke Dialog).

Comment: Did you try this?

Comment: It appears to be @TomášZato's problem to just get the letters separated. So after the ungroup he would already have what he needs. The 'break apart' part is not necessary.

Answer (score -1):

Nobody could answer with exact answer so here's the best I could figure out. We ended up with this poor thing:

[image: image description]

The answer to the problem is **Path - Difference** (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>-</kbd>) from the main menu.
[image: image description]

You have to do it for every letter but it works.

Comment: Mind explaining the downvote? This is what the question asks for...